# how to show error log of azure web service?

Tags: azure

I have a dotnet core 2.2 web app running on azure, and sometimnes I get:

An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-d43c34214967214b8b90bf06f1bc60c2-b09f68b988d89243-00
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

where can I find the stack trace or any further info of the error ? azure is that complicated, I spent 2 hours on trying to activate protocolls , insights and so on - is there an easy way to get the error message ?

thankx mike

Comment: If you have enabled application insights take a look there.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to your service then "überwachungen/App-Service Protokolle"
2. switch on the protocolls you would like to be saved
3. go to "Protokollstream" and connect to "Anwendungsprotokolle" (applicationProtocolls"